# using .find() method to find productId as a parameter base on the productId click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, parameters

Right now, am getting the productId at match.params.id but when I used the find method to compare the item.id and match.params.id it return product not found....below is the code

```
const DetailsPage = (props) => {
    console.log(props.match.params.id)
    const product = data.products.find((item) => item.id === props.match.params.id)
    console.log(product);
    if (!product) {
        return (
            <h1>Product Not Found</h1>
        )
    }
    return (
        <div>
            DetailsPage
                {product.name}
        </div>
    )
```

As you can see I console.log(props.match.params.id) which gave me the product parameterId but nothing exist in my declaration of the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because id retrieved from the route will be of type `string`. Since you are doing `===` strict equals find will fail .

You can type cast your params.id to `Number`.

```
const product = data.products.find((item) => item.id === Number(props.match.params.id))
```

Also `react-router` now provides a `useParams` hook to retrieve the params .

```
let { id } = useParams();
```